# sum an especial index in array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

How can I sum an especial index in array for example I wanna sum -age(it's an index) in this array:

```
$users = array(

    "user1" => array("name" => "Loghman Avand", "age" => 26),
    "user2" => array("name" => "Sara Alavi", "age" => 34),
    "user3"=> array("name" => "Hossein Ahmadi", "age" => 3)
);
```

Comment: Your array is invalid. Key of array must be unique other wise its overwrite with last value.

Comment: @B.Desai is correct! Please look at the array first @ Mahdi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_column() and array_sum():

```
 $ages = array_column($users, 'age');
 echo 'Sum is: ', array_sum($ages);
```

This is ignoring the fact your keys in the outer array are the same.

Answer (score -2):

First thing is your above array is invalid. Because same array key ('users') is used mode than one time. 
Check this below code

```
$users = array("user1" => array("name" => "Loghman Avand", "age" => 26), "user2" => array("name" => "Sara Alavi", "age" => 34), "user3" => array("name" => "Hossein Ahmadi", "age" => 3));
$age_sum = 0;
foreach($users as $user){
    $age_sum += $user['age'];
}
echo $age_sum;
```